# Why is List.length linear in complexity?

Tags: list, f#

I understand that lists are implemented as singly linked so they don't really have a constant structure that you can pin a length on, but each node should know how many nodes till the last element right? There isn't a way to add a node to some existing list and for that node not to be able to determine the length of the list it represents in constant time provided that the existing nodes already have that info.

I can understand why that wouldn't work in Haskell, for example, due to lazyness, but as far as I know F# lists aren't lazy. So, is the problem just in the extra memory overhead?

Comment: Why would it be valuable to keep a length of the remaining list with each node?  Every time you added an item on the end of the list, you'd have to increment the value of that variable in each node.  Sounds like a lot of extra processing to me...  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @TrippKinetics : You cannot add an item to the end of a functional list, only to the beginning.

Comment: What about `List.append`?

Comment: @TrippKinetics you need to refresh your FP :P (F#'s lists are immutable and List.append rewrites the complete first list)

Comment: @TrippKinetics : That creates a new list, duplicating each node, unlike `(::)`.

Comment: @LukaHorvat you could do this of course but it's only the length after all - why waste this much space for a simple property? (FP is quite old ... at this time space was quite expensive) - and on top in lazy functional langs. (Haskell for example) there are infinite lists where you could not do this (interesting bit for Tripp: here it looks as though the tail of the list is appended all the time ;) )

Comment: @CarstenKönig Because if I want to avoid my functions having quadratic complexity I have to pass around the length along with the accumulator.

Comment: @LukaHorvat ... err you pass the accumulator already ... rather rewrite the complete List-core than passing a simple tuple?

Comment: @CarstenKönig What? How is that ever a good argument? If List-core does something less efficiently than it could then yes, you rewrite it. Just because I can pass around a parameter that gets around that obstacle doesn't mean it shouldn't be improved. And it's really not like this is an uncommon pattern. Now, I'm not saying that it IS broken. The memory overhead is probably a reasonable setback since it's linear in space complexity, but I was just looking for an explanation.

Comment: we are talking about lists here - if performance and efficiency is an issue FP-lists are rarely the answer ... and this is about their *length* ... and yes in FP adding a function or tuple as as an argument **IS** usually a good argument

Comment: Lists are one of the founding priciples of FP (**LIS**t**P**rocessing) and you would make the theory harder and the possibilites smaller if you added length to the definition

Comment: @ildjarn Yeah, but since F# already "solved" that problem with sequences, I don't think it really matters.

Comment: Maintaining the length property would cause all sorts of concurrency issues if the list was used from within multiple threads. It would need locking to be safe, and it comes with additional performance penalty.

Comment: @Endrju It wouldn't update. The length is a fixed property of a list node.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me like typical memory vs time performance consideration.

If standard f# list had the implementation You suggest, then it would need much more place in memory (consider one million long list of bools). And everyone using such list would have to deal with it. There would be no simple way to opt out of this other than writing completely new implementation of list.

On the other hand, it seems to be fairly simple to create a new type that would store length of succeeding list with each element basing on F# List. You can implement it on Your own if You need it. Those, who don't need it will use standard implementation.

Comment: but why? You produce those lists - if you want you can produce them as tuples `Value*Lenght` if you wanted and get the same without having to touch anything!

Comment: Is Your question related to my idea of creating a new type? I suggested creating new type instead of using tuple just because it was first that came to my mind. Still, my reasoning remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

I don't often find myself needing to know the length of the list, it's not like you need it to exit a `for` loop like you would with arrays in imperative languages.

For those rare cases when you really need to know the length asap, you can go with Carsten König's suggestion from a comment and make your `'a list` into a `('a * int) list`, where each node keeps the length of the tail as a tuple element.

Then you can have something like this:

```
let push lst e =
    match lst with
    | (_, c)::_ -> (e, c + 1) :: lst
    | [] -> [e, 0]
```

and `length` and `pop` functions to match.

For all the other cases I'd call it a premature optimization.

Comment: Maybe my case was more specific than I thought.